# Zigbee stack on Linux (mainline kernel)?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, zigbee, mesh-network

I'm planning to use Zigbee on a Linux embedded computer.

Is there such thing as a Zigbee Linux stack ? (similar to a TCP/IP stack)
Is it included in mainline kernel ?

Ideally, I would like to have a minimalist USB Zigbee RF (802.15.4) transceiver connected to an embedded computer and most of the work would be done in this Zigbee software stack.

Does such a thing exist ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is described at [Documentation/networking/ieee802154.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/networking/ieee802154.txt). What you are looking for is most likely this excerpt:

> ## Socket API
>
> `int sd = socket(PF_IEEE802154, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);`
>
> .....
>
> The address family, socket addresses etc. are defined in the
>   `include/net/af_ieee802154.h` header or in the special header
>   in the userspace package (see either http://wpan.cakelab.org/ or the
>   git tree at https://github.com/linux-wpan/wpan-tools).
>
> One can use `SOCK_RAW` for passing raw data towards device `xmit` function. YMMV.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31071001/zigbee-kernel-driver) question.